# Python Paypal REST SDK Integration issue

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11 for a project. I am using paypalrestsdk 1.13.1(Paypal REST SDK) package for Paypal Integration. I have been following the steps provided in - 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK
and
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/payments/

Following is my view.py

```
def donateThroughPaypal(request):
context = locals()
approval_url = ""
redirect_url = ""

if request.method == 'POST':
    paypalrestsdk.configure({
      'mode': 'sandbox', #sandbox or live
      'client_id': '<client_id>',
      'client_secret': '<client_secret>' })

    payment = Payment({"intent": "sale",
                        # Set payment method
                        "payer": {"payment_method": "paypal"},
                        # Set redirect urls
                        "redirect_urls": {"return_url": "http://localhost:8000/Return.html",
                                            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8000/Cancel.html"},
                        # Set transaction object
                        "transactions": [{"amount": {"total": "10.00","currency": "USD"},
                                            "description": "transaction payment description"}]})        

    if payment.create():            
        for link in payment.links:                
            if link.rel == "approval_url":                    
                approval_url = str(link.href)                    
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                redirect_url = str(link.href)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(approval_url)
    else:
        print(payment.error)
template = 'donate/donate.html'
return render(request,template,context)
```

So the line `return HttpResponseRedirect(approval_url)` redirects me to Paypal login page.  However, when I login into sandbox with buyer account, Paypal responds with - **Return to Merchant** and this redirects to `cancel_url`.

I am successfully getting the `token=EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and `payment_id=PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.

Please assist. Let me know if I am missing any setup.

Also, is there any end-to-end (client-to-server), step wise documentation for Python - Paypal REST API integration? Please let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use an existing library ? ie: https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal (I'm not the author).

Comment: @ClémentDenoix I had read about the library you suggested long time ago. I didn't understand it. So I moved on to Python Paypal REST SDK. The steps and documentation were/are understandable.

Comment: strange behavior - can you possibly paste the request / response JSON? does the login page open in a light box ?

Comment: hi, @vaibhavshetti I'm also struggling with PayPal python rest SDK but I'm stuck on the client side. I don't know how I can pass csrf-token from client side within the PayPal script. can you help me, how you have submitted the request from template to this view?